# controller scope not working in separate html page

Tags: angularjs

I tried to hide some menus using a controller. Here is my element container where the menu will be loaded.

```
<div class="page-content" ng-controller = "menuController">
    <div id="Menu"  > </div>
    <div ng-view> </div>            
</div>

<script> 

    $(function(){
      $("#Menu").load("Menu.html");
    });

    app.controller("menuController", function($scope) {
        $scope.showMenu = false;    
    });

</script>
```

I wrote the menu in seperate html file.

```
<div class="category-content no-padding"> 

        <ul ng-show= "showMenu">
            <li><a href="#org"><i class="fa fa-h-square text-brown" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Organization</span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#Main"><i class="fa fa-hospital-o text-brown" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Clinic</span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#User"><i class="fa fa-user text-brown" aria-hidden="true"></i><span >User</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

But for me scope variable declared in the controller does not have any impact on menu. Please help me to overcome this.

Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: Is that separate HTML file a child of the DOM node defining the controller?  If not, then it would explain the controller does not have any "impact."

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes. <div class="page-content" ng-controller = "menuController">
    <div id="Menu"  > </div>
    <div ng-view> </div>            
</div>

Comment: Use ng-view and ng-If in combination in place of jQuery load.

Comment: @MuhammadRamzan but what if i want to restrict some menu items?

Comment: By using ng-view and then applying ng-controller on your menu view and then route your path to new controller and pass data which you want to new controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing Jquery code with Angular code is not very good.
You can use angular's ng-include directive to load your menu:

```
<div class="page-content" ng-controller = "menuController">
    <div ng-include="'Menu.html'"  > </div>
    <div ng-view> </div>            
</div>
```

Depending on the location of Menu.html, you may have to precise the entire path, for example:

```
<div> ng-include="'folder/subfolder/Menu.html'" </div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate it worked.  may I know the reason why it failed?

Comment: maybe Menu.html is loaded after the controller is instantiated ... maybe angular doesn't detect the new added html in jquery way, ....